# Creating firefox plugin to retieve certificate details

Tags: firefox-addon, ssl-certificate

I want to  create a simple firefox plugin which displays the details of the certificate os a website. Is this possible to get details even if the website's certificate is not a trusted certificate. How to Make this. I am good at HTML, Javascript. 
thanks 
regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is possible. The Firefox UI that displays the information (and/or error page, Add Exception dialog) is XUL (XML user interface language) + Javascript + CSS.

There are already a couple of add-ons which use/display the certificate information, e.g. the open-source [CipherFox](https://github.com/gavinhungry/cipherfox) add-on.

You can also always read the mozilla code itself (e.g. online via [mxr](http://mxr.mozilla.org/)). A good place to start would probably be `exceptionDialog.xul` and related files, that provide the UI for adding security exceptions.

But first, you'd need to read up on creating extensions in general, I guess.

- [Extensions on DevMo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions), mainly concerning "old-school" XUL-overlay add-ons
- [Developer Hub on AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/)
- [Add-on SDK and Builder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder)
- [Add-on SDK vs. XUL-overlay add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/sdk-vs-xul.html)